# Speed of Java and Python implementation

Tags: java, python, performance, big-o

So I have a problem that I have already solved in both python and java. The problem is, for a multiplication table of 8000*8000 elements, find all the unique numbers:

Python:

```
table = 8000
unique_prods = []
start = 1

for i in range(table*table + 1):
    unique_prods.append(0)

for x in range(1, table + 1):
    for y in range(start, table + 1):
        # print '{:4}'.format(x * y),
        if not unique_prods[x * y] == x * y:
            unique_prods[x * y] = x * y
    start += 1
    # print

# print unique_prods
print len(unique_prods)
```

Java:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int table = 8000;
        int [] myArray = new int[table*table + 1];
        int count = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < table*table + 1; i++) {
            myArray[i] = 0;
        }

        for (int x = 1; x < table + 1; x++) {
            for (int y = count; y < table + 1; y++) {
                if (! (myArray[x * y] == x * y)) {
                    myArray[x * y] = x * y;
                }
            }
            count += 1;
//            System.out.println(count);
        }

        count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < table*table + 1; i++) {
            if(myArray[i] != 0) {
                count += 1;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

I found it astonishing that the Java implementation took a second, and the Python version took over a minute. Is there a way to boost up the python performance so that it becomes closer to the speed of the Java implementation?

Comment: Oh, I saw now that the Python would spit out the wrong answer, but that can be easily fixed by iterating through the list. Sorry about that.

Comment: Why are you checking if `myArray[x * y]` does not equal `x * y` before setting it equal to `x * y`? If it is already equal then setting it equal to itself does not change its value. If it is not already equal then it will be set to `x * y`. The `if` is superfluous.

Comment: `for i in range(table*table + 1): unique_prods.append(0)` should be replaced with `unique_prods=[0]*(table*table + 1)` which is 15 times faster on my machine.

Comment: @Peter Bah! Beat me to it by a few seconds.

Comment: To ask for feedback on *working code*, you'd be better of asking on CodeReview.SE.

Comment: @curiousinternals I am not setting it equal to itself, myArray is filled with 0s first, then it is filled with values so that I can get all the unique multiplications. How would you suggest me filling an array with the unique multiplications?

Comment: @Peter thanks for the heads up, but that operation is a constant in my algorithm, and won't make things much faster. The computational problem lies in the double for-loop and the checking of the value. The complexity of the algorithm is O(x^2) I think, and that's probably where I could make things faster.

Comment: @ArashSaidi I think you misunderstood my comment. I said **if** `myArray[x * y]` **is already equal to** `x * y`, then nothing changes. Regardless of whether the condition for that if statement is true or false, **the outcome is the same**. The if statement can be removed and te behaviour of the code will not change.

Comment: @curiousinternals Yeah, I completely misunderstood, and now that I see it, it's just so obvious. I see that people have said that I should post this in code review, but I think this is a SO question because we are comparing two methods, looking at the complexity of algorithms, and seeing if we can improve by having a discussion. I think these kind of questions belong here in SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Python code is not optimal, you wouldn't solve the problem the same way as in Java:

```
table = 8000
unique_prods = set()

for x in range(1, table + 1):
    for y in range(x, table + 1):
        unique_prods.add(x * y)
print len(unique_prods)
```

takes 14s on my computer.
But it is clear, that python takes longer for mere mathematical problems, because Python has no integrated JIT-Compiler. For calculations, there is a package called numpy, that speeds up things dramatically:

```
import numpy
x = numpy.arange(1,8001)
unique_prods = numpy.zeros(8000*8000+1,dtype='b')
for k in x:
    unique_prods[k*x[k-1:]]=1
print unique_prods.sum()
```

and you get your result in 0.8s. In contrast to a C version, which needs only 0.6s.

Comment: Obviously, Java version also should use the set approach. So this doesn't make sense. Either compare two optimal implementations, or two non-optimal. Claiming that Python is different in this regard from Java is wrong.

Comment: On my computer the set approach in python is simpler, but significantly slower, than using a list of length table*table.

Comment: That's really fast. Can you please explain what you are doing. I can't understand the line unique_prods[k*x[k-1:]]=1

Answer (score 0):

Python may be slower, but consider the following two snippets as more pythonic:

```
import time 
starttime = time.time()
table = 8000
unique_prods = [0] * (table*table + 1)
for x in range(1, table+1):
    for y in range(1, table+1):
        unique_prods[x*y] = 1

elapsed = time.time() - starttime
print((elapsed, sum(unique_prods)))
```

and the simplest, but not necessarily fastest:

```
starttime = time.time()
table = 8000
unique = set(x*y for x in range(1, table+1) for y in range(1,table+1))
elapsed = time.time() - starttime
print((elapsed, len(unique)))
```

Python isn't designed to be the fastest. The python advantage is that you can write

```
unique = set(x*y for x in range(1, table+1) for y in range(1,table+1))
print(len(unique))
```

as basically a one-liner that clearly solves the underlying mathematical problem, namely defining a set and printing its cardinality.

Comment: Use `timeit` to compare implementations more reliably.

Comment: And as with the other answer: it doesn't make sense to change the underlying algorithm in only one implementation when comparing with the other.

Comment: @BartoszKP: I was comparing to anything, just showing some options.

Comment: And the question is related to a comparison between Python and Java.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be with how you create your array in python.

Consider the following:

```
array = []

for i in range(8000*8000 + 1):
  array.append(0)
```

This took a long time to run (14s for me) because we first create an empty array and then resize it a total of 64000001 times. Instead of doing this you should create an array of the correct size so that only one memory allocation is required:

```
array = [0] * (8000*8000 + 1) // Creates an array filled with zeros of size (8000*8000 + 1)
```

This code ran almost instantly for me.

Comment: Have you tried to compare the whole program with, and without this fix?

Comment: @BartoszKP I just did and it revealed that my first test gave a wildly inaccurate result. I'm not sure why it took a minute instead of 14s the first time (stuff running in the background?), but I guess that teaches me to do repeat tests. Back to the drawing board...

Comment: Python has `timeit` module for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noticed, the way you expand the list is one thing that is in favor of your Java implementation of this algorithm. This simple fix:

```
unique_prods = [0] * (table*table + 1)
```

yields the following results of your algorithm (with implementation otherwise exactly the same of you've posted):

```
python -m timeit -n 10 -r 1 "import test" "test.testWithFix()"
64000001
64000001
64000001
64000001
64000001
64000001
64000001
64000001
64000001
64000001
10 loops, best of 1: 31.6 sec per loop
```

---

```
python -m timeit -n 10 -r 1 "import test" "test.testWithoutFix()"
64000001
64000001
64000001
64000001
64000001
64000001
64000001
64000001
64000001
64000001
10 loops, best of 1: 62.9 sec per loop
```

Also, both your implementations are wrong (you should use a set) and have other minor inaccuracies (like redundant `if` statement mentioned in the comments).